# Make outbound Teams PSTN call - Azure Communication Services Teams Interoperability

Tags: microsoft-teams

I try to implement a PSTN call feature using Azure Communication Services Teams Interoperability referring this sample code and use case:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-javascript-quickstarts/tree/main/add-1-on-1-cte-video-calling
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/interop/custom-teams-endpoint-use-cases#use-case-1-make-outbound-teams-pstn-call

I added the following code to the sample, but I got an error.

```
startPSTNButton.addEventListener('click',async () => {
    try {
        console.log('PSTN IN');
        const pstnCallee = { phoneNumber: '+81311112222' }
        const oneToOneCall = teamsCallAgent.startCall([pstnCallee], { threadId: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' });

        console.log('Call out');
        // Subscribe to the call's properties and events.
        subscribeToCall(oneToOneCall);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

**Error:**

```
CallingCommunicationError: Starting a one to one with thread ID is invalid.
    at TeamsCallAgentImpl.startCall (sdk.bundle.js:183:140138)
    at W.value (sdk.bundle.js:161:2267)
    at HTMLButtonElement. (client.js:311:1) (anonymous) @ client.js:317
```

Is threadId: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' correct?
How to fix the error?

Comment: Could you please use Thread Id as Megan team id? You will get the id using below Graph API.
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Permissions: User.ReadBasic.All (delegated)
Response: response.body.value[1].displayName; // ”Megan Bowen”
   response.body.value[1].id; // "e8b753b5-4117-464e-9a08-713e1ff2xxxx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out, and threadId is not required.
https://github.com/Azure/Communication/blob/master/releasenotes/acs-javascript-calling-library-release-notes.md#170-beta1-2022-08-01

```
 const phoneCallee = { phoneNumber: '<PHONE_NUMBER_E164_FORMAT>' }
 const oneToOneCall = teamsCallAgent.startCall(phoneCallee );
```

I try this, and it works fine.